# Import CSV as polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, csv

I have a CSV file with the coordinates of the vertices of my polygons (in the picture they correspond to "left", "right", "top", "bottom"). Actually is a grid of polygons. How can I import the file in QGIS as polygons and not as points?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the rectangles with diagonal *(left,top)* and *(right,bottom)* as the required polygons.

You could import the CSV as points, say *x=left*, *y=top*, and then use processing (or even expressions) which access *right* and *bottom* as attributes and transform to the desired rectangles.

However, it will be faster to preprocess within Excel (or whatever your spreadsheet program is) by combining the attributes into a WKT Polygon string, which unambiguously specifies the polygons in a standard format.

In cell G2 (or row 2 of a new column if G is used), put `="POLYGON(("&B2&" "&C2&", "&D2&" "&C2&", "&D2&" "&E2&", "&B2&" "&E2&", "&B2&" "&C2&"))"` and copy it down. It generates a polygon WKT string that goes around the points clockwise. You can then import the CSV taking the geometry from this column and QGIS will interpret it as a polygon (rectangle) for each line.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it with expressions, even loading your excel file, without converting to .csv, load your excel file as if it was a vectorial layer

On the **process toolbox** > **vector geometry** > **geometry by expression**.
[image]

[image]

The expression, although it looks a little long, is simply to write a wkt polygon using the fields, then you convert it to geometry.
[image]

Simply run this expression

```
 geom_from_wkt( concat('POLYGON((',to_string("left")+' '+to_string("top")+',',to_string("right")+' '+to_string("top")+', ', to_string("right")+' '+to_string("bottom")+',', to_string("left")+' '+to_string("bottom"),'))
```

You will get a result like this:

[image]