# Can't read coordinates from CSV file

Tags: qgis, coordinates, csv

I'm trying to import a CSV file with geolocated attributes, but the format is not recognized:

[image: Exemple]

Is there a way to automatically recognized it?

EDIT: I think what I need is a batch converter to replace (for example) 9.8N /42.8W by 9.8 / -42.8. I'm looking for that tool.

IDT 2: here is the csv sample https://gofile.io/d/8QsYwb

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the same approach with `"Geometry by expression"` described in [@Luis Perez's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/378053/99589). However, deploy a bit different expression

```py
make_point(
    if(regexp_match("Longitude (deg.)", 'W'),
    -regexp_substr("Longitude (deg.)" ,'[^A-Z]+'),
    regexp_substr("Longitude (deg.)" ,'[^A-Z]+')
    ),
    if(regexp_match("Latitude (deg.)",'S'),
    -regexp_substr("Latitude (deg.)" ,'[^A-Z]+'),
    regexp_substr("Latitude (deg.)" ,'[^A-Z]+')
    )
)
```

[image: geometry_by_expression]

And get the output

[image: result]

Using [`transform()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html#geometry-functions) is allowable.

---

**References:**

- [Docs » QGIS User Guide » 23.1.15.35. Geometry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression)

Comment: I get the idea, but your expression doesn't work :/

Comment: No error, but the attributes still cannot be geolocalized (the coordinates format still unchanged)

Comment: Done in my 1st post ;)

Comment: Can you please give a hint what do your points represent?

Comment: These are the fireballs reported by US government sensors for the last 30 years :)
Thank you for you assistance, your trick will be useful for me for future work !

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I've fixed such problems in Excel. Add a column, filter for anything tagged S or W and calculate -1 in that column, and fill the rest with 1's. Find replace to get ride of all the NSEW characters. Then multiply column values by either 1 or -1.